# Error installing Spyder with conda - python

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I've tried multiple ways to install Spyder using conda using Anaconda Prompt within a Windows OS. It's been a nightmare. The consistent message I'm getting is:

`Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done`
`Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.`
`Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repo data from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repo data source.`
`Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done`
`Solving environment:`

After activating a new env, I've tried to install Spyder using the following commands:

1. conda install spyder
2. conda install -c anaconda spyder
3. conda install -c conda-forge spyder
4. I've downgraded the python version to 3.7 and ran both 1,2,3 again but am still getting the same response.

Comment: Update conda , create a clean environment ,update conda environment , Try to Install Spyder , check conflicting Packages , rmeove cache files , check config of conda